# Better way to use repair with cassandra db

Tags: database, cassandra, repair

evebody.

After migrated a new cluster cassandra, I will need to repair the nodes. What the better sintax to use in this case? -pr , -seq or -full?

And the maintaince weekly? -pr ou -seq? The -pr i need to apply every node the same time or one after another? My environment have 5 nodes (2 seeds).

Nobody explain this point.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Repair is just ensure the consistency of the data on Cassandra cluster.Repair synchronizes the data between nodes by comparing their respective datasets for their common token ranges, and streaming the differences for any out of sync sections between the nodes. It compares the data with merkle trees, which are a hierarchy of hashes.After migration, you should run full repair on each node. once full repair successfully completed you may go with other options like -pr or -inc or -seq. Please refer below link for more undertsnading
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesManualRepair.html

Comment: That´ ok. If I need to use the repair full, will be in each node? Or every nodes? One after another or the same time. This is the big question.

Comment: You should run full repair on each node one by one but not in parallel because repair is highly io intensive operation.